# Web form does not make the correct reply

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, forms

I have a asp.net c# site with a property reply form to the seller member at
www.somewebsite.com.  When a reply is sent, the email address from
the sender  is just regular text and I need it to be a link.

That is, the receiving members should be able to just click on the senders email address and open it in the members email client to reply. How do I do that in code? I am not a developer but owner but can make minor code changes and  check it in.

Comment: can you share the snippet of code that outputs the email now?

Comment: from the title, I take it the OP is a rapper.

Comment: @shadowfoxmi yo don't know that fo sho

Comment: And now that the title has been edited, no one will understand the source of our amusement.

Comment: Please post the original title - the suspense is killing my colleagues and I ...

Answer (score 1):

If it is HTML email, you can put a mailto around the email.

```
<a href="mailto:someone@somewhere.com">person's email address</a>
```

That should do it, as long as the email is in HTML format.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the mail is being sent by ASP.Net using the `System.Net.MailMessage` class, you need to ensure that the `MailMessage.From` property is correctly set. More info here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.from.aspx